# Creating an Amazon S3 Bucket using jQuery and REST

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, amazon-s3

I am wanting to try and do a handful of things with the use of jQuery and Amazons S3 API via REST. My key issue is not being familiar with REST well enough (or not as well as I thought I knew) to know if this approach would even remotely work right. I have tried searching endlessly for some tidbit of an example and came up fruitless, maybe I am searching for the wrong things I don't know, but as a last ditch effort I figured I'd hit up my new favorite place, here..

What I need to do is send. PUT a request to the API to create the bucket. Based on the S3 API docs I came up with

```
var AWSAccessKeyId = "";
var AWSSecretAccessKey = "";
var AWSDomain = ".s3.amazonaws.com";

function createNewBucket(bucketName)
{
    var bucketString = 'HTTP/1.1\n';
    bucketString += bucketName + AWSDomain + '\n';
    bucketString += 'Content-Length: 0 \n';
    bucketString += 'Date: Wed, 01 Mar  2009 12:00:00 GMT \n';
    bucketString += 'Authorization: AWS ' +  sha1_string;

    $.ajax({
        url: bucketName + AWSDomain,
        type: 'PUT',
        data: bucketString,
        success: function(data) 
        {

        },
        error: ''
    });
}
```

though concept isn't complete with the above I am just starting it out, and I started questioning if this idea of approach was even going to work.. And if it is to work with the above or in any means provided here for help how would I also work with the response to know if it was successful or not? I know if I can nail this one piece down I can handle for the most part the rest of my issues to come. Its just tackling the first hump and figuring out if I am going about it the right way. Its also worth mentioning that I have been tasked with doing this purely javascript style with or without the help of a lib like jquery. I can't use PHP, or the like in this concept. So if anyone can throw me a bone i'd be greatly appreciative.

On a side note, does anyone know if theres a means of actually testing something like this stuff out without actually having a S3 account, cause I can't afford to pay for an account just for the sake of testing let alone any other reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I am getting the feeling that you are quite new to consuming web-services client side.
It is often best to start with something simple.

If I have a resource that returns a string... say **test.html -> "Hello World!"**
And the URL for this web-service is **some-realy-long-id.s3.amazonaws.com**
then we have the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'some-realy-long-id.s3.amazonaws.com/test.html',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: {
        'myKey':'myValue'
    },
    success: function(data) {

        //alert dialog containing "Hello World!"
        alert(data);
    },
    error: ''
});
```

You must remember that requests from the browser follow the same-origin policy, so unless you are planning to use **JSOP**, or some other cross-domain hack you will run into trouble.

p.s. another little piece of advice is to use right hand braces in Javascript as it performs semi-colon insertion (which will bite you if you return a object literal).

Oh yes and a lot of old browsers do not support 'PUT' which you may need to consider.

Comment: Im more concerned with am I sending the data right at the moment such as the use of "bucketString" in my little example. Also I notice in your example you have "data:" twice, doesn't one over write the other?

Comment: Since you appear new to Javascript, I would definitely recommend reading and listening to any content from **douglas crockford**, I't will enlighten you to the fundamentals (and nature) of Javascript - just don't take him as too seriously tho.

Comment: Also have a good look at the parameters in $.ajax [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you man not want to full REST due to browser compatibility and the parameter URL is just that - A url. Other HTTP headers are set though the other properties.